# Github Projects Workflows not working - Cards not moved after PullRequest related Actions

Tags: github, github-projects

I have some trouble with the github projects feature.
I Have a ticket board with different lanes. I would like to have my cards moved to specific lanes, if e.g. a Pull Request (linked to the issue) is closed or approved.

When I close an issue by myself, without the issue being autoclosed by github, the assigned workflow works. But all github related workflows refuse to work.

All my workflows are enabled.

1. Pull Request approved => move to "Testing"
2. Pull Request merged => move to "Ready for Release"
3. Pull Request closed => move to "Testing" (thats an old one, but github moved them to "Done" automatically.

Do you have any ideas how to fix that?